# Session Variable not available in FlowRef Lookup Table

Tags: mule, lookup, datamapper, mule-component, mule-el

I am using a Message Enricher to call a web services and return what a part number is for the external data source. I am saving that payload into a Session Variable. I am then using a Lookup Table from within a Datamapper to send the current payloads' part number to be referenced against the external data source (using xpath). I am able to invoke the Lookup and pass the local variable but the payload that was saved into the Session Variable is not being passed through to the Lookup Flow, so my xpath query will not work.

Here is the Session Variable and Datamapper

```
<flow>
<enricher target="#[sessionVars['SesVar']]" doc:name="Message Enricher">
    <flow-ref name="query-line-details-erpFlow" doc:name="query-line-details-erpFlow"/>
</enricher>
<logger message="Session Var: #[sessionVars['SesVar']]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
<data-mapper:transform config-ref="XML_To_XML" doc:name="XML To XML"/>
</flow>
```

Here is the Lookup Table logic

```
output.ExternalPart = (isnull(lookup(LookUpPart).get([input.LocalPart])) ? null : lookup(LookUpPart).get([input.LocalPart]).ExternalPart);
```

Finally here is the second flow where the Session Var should be accessed from

```
<flow>
 <logger message="Spit out the var #[sessionVars.SesVar]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
</flow>
```

From what research I have done, the Session Variable is not passing a Transport Barrier so it should be able to be referenced from this scope. I have also tried with flowVars also.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.